# Using nightwatch elementIdText value

Tags: testing

So I have a div that contains some text followed by a link. Im using nightwatch to write some tests. How do I use the result of

```
browser
  .elementIdText('elementId')
  .url("how do I use the url from elementIdText ?!")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The string value returned by your `.elementIdText('elementId')` can be used inside it's callback function. Your code would be like this:

```
browser
  .elementIdText('elementId', function(result){
    browser.url(result)
})
```